# In SML - Why doesn't simple recursion always return 0 if first expression met?

Tags: recursion, smlnj

In a simple recursion with first if expression true then 0.   if steps in the recursion keeps going until that first expression is true, why isn't 0 always returned?

```
fun stepping (n  :  int, number  :  int)  = 
     if number > n
     then 0
     else   1 + stepping (n, number + 1)
```

It seems like the function stepping should add one onto number until number > n  and then always return 0.   Instead, it returns the number of times you went through the recursion cycle until number becomes greater than n.

The above code tests good in SML and gave me what I wanted - the number of steps incrementing by 1 until input "number" is greater than the input "n".   But manually walking through the recursion steps, it seems like the return should always be 0 when the incremented "number" > the input "n".  What am I missing?

Comment: Ask yourself why `1 + stepping (n, number + 1)` would be zero. (Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. In particular, they return to their immediate caller and nowhere else. )

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaking the result of the final call to `stepping` in the recursive chain (which will always be zero) as being the ultimate value returned by the expression, but that is not the case. It is actually part of a larger equation that makes up the overall returned value.

For example, if we look at how the expression gets built up as each recursive call is made when evaluating `stepping(3, 1)`, you end up with...

```
result = stepping(3, 1)
result = 1 + stepping(3, 2)
result = 1 + 1 + stepping(3, 3)
result = 1 + 1 + 1 + stepping(3, 4)
result = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
result = 3
```

Comment: Thank you of doing the manual step through to show me what is happening.   So, it is the cumulative return of the function vice the final step with the return of the fucntion  by default in sml starting at 0 for an int return or [] fpr a list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that I'm going to give you some money this year, according to this scheme:

- you get nothing on the first of January
- on all other days, you get one dollar more than I would have given you the day before

How much would I have to pay you today, the 20th of February?
Fifty dollars or nothing at all?
If you follow the calendar backwards, you will eventually reach January 1st, where the payment is zero, so would you expect to get nothing?

To answer your immediate question: the function *does* always return 0 if the first condition is met – that is, `if number > n`.

However, if the first condition *isn't* met – `number <= n` – it does not return 0 but `1 + stepping (n, number + 1)`.
It works exactly like of you called a function with a different name; that function computes a value and then this function adds 1.

It's *not* like returning a value from inside a loop, such as (pseudocode)

```
while (true)
{
    if number > n
        return 0
    else 
        number = number +1
}
```

which is perhaps what you're thinking about.